# XSSFWorkbook won't load a small Excel file

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, hssfworkbook

I've tried to initialize an XSSFWorkbook with an Excel file with the .xlsm extension using Apache POI in Java, but it's taking a lot of time to load the file (I've already waited 1 hour and it was still loading). The xlsm file itself is fairly small (1MB), has 50 sheets (each sheet has one table constituted by 5x20 cells) and a Macro script. The code I'm currently using is:

```
String templateFilePath = filePath + fileName + ".xlsm";
XSSFWorkbook newWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook(templateFilePath);
```

Please note that I've tried to load the file using:

```
Workbook newWorkBook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(templateFilePath) );


Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(templateFilePath));
File file =  new File(templateFilePath);


File file = new File(templateFilePath);
OPCPackage opcPackage = OPCPackage.open(file);
XSSFWorkbook newWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook(opcPackage);
```

... And still got the same results. Also, I've tried other file extensions (.xlsx and .xls) to no avail.

Other notes: 
No memory errors are displayed. It just keeps infinitely loading the file.
I've made another test where I deleted some sheets from the file and left only 8. That way the "newWorkBook" was successfully initialized. However, I need to read the file with all the sheets so I'd like to know if there is another way to do so.

Comment: Use a [File](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream) rather than an InputStream?

Comment: @Gagravarr I already tried that but I got the same results. Do you another suggestions?

Comment: Do a thread dump and see where it's blocked?

Comment: I solved the problem. Apparently POI doesn't work well with comments in cells so I removed all the comments with a Macro. Now the XSSFWorkbook initializes. Thank you for your help!